# Getting the empty string from entry textbox instead of value entered

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a textbox in a tkinter window which is called by a button.
I want to get the value of textbox in another window on clicking a button.
But when i print the value on console, it prints an empty string instead of the value entered in textbox.

```
from tkinter import *

def click():
    print(id.get())

def submit():
    win2=Tk()
    Label1=Label(win2,text='Id').pack()
    global id
    id=StringVar()
    textbox=Entry(win2,textvariable=id).pack()
    btn2=Button(win2,text='Click',command=click).pack()

win1=Tk()
btn1=Button(win1,text='Submit',command=submit).pack()
```

Please check my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From previous answer by @neko,i got an answer similar to my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def click():
    print(textbox.get())

def submit():
    win2=Tk()
    Label1=Label(win2,text='Id').pack()
    global textbox
    id=StringVar()
    textbox=Entry(win2,textvariable=id)
    textbox.pack()
    btn2=Button(win2,text='Click',command=click).pack()


win1=Tk()
btn1=Button(win1,text='Submit',command=submit).pack()
```

The problem was that i was using id.get(), which is not working in multiple tkinter window. So now i used textbox.get() which is working fine here.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainPage(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.btn1 = tk.Button(self, text='Submit', command=self.submit)
        self.btn1.pack()

    def submit(self):
        self.win2 = tk.Tk()
        self.Label1 = tk.Label(self.win2, text='Id')
        self.Label1.pack()
        self.id = tk.StringVar()
        self.textbox = tk.Entry(self.win2, textvariable=self.id)
        self.textbox.pack()
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self.win2, text='Click', command=self.click)
        self.btn2.pack()

    def click(self):
        print(self.textbox.get())

interface = MainPage()
interface.mainloop()
```

*Edit*: The main difference with the original code is that the `print` calls the Entry widget, rather than the `StringVar`. If you would like to set the `StringVar` to the text inserted in the textbox, then you would have to call at some point

```
self.id.set(self.textbox.get())
```

then the `self.id.get()` would return what you expect.

Comment: This answer would be better with an explanation. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the code in the question line by line and character by character to see what you've done differently.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to do this? :

`print(id.get("1.0",'end-1c'))`

The '1.0' part tells the method to start reading at the first line (starting with the first character, because of the 0). The 'end-1c' argument tells the method to read until it reaches the end of the text. Note that 1c removes 1 character from the text, because if you used just 'end', it would add a new line character at the end of your text.

Comment: It is showing error after using                                                                `print(id.get("1.0",'end-1c'))`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            as TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given